# how to Parse Json Arabic text in java

Tags: java, json, spring-rest

I cannot parse json arabic test.I am sending request in json as
`{"SUBJECT_AR":"أهلا بك"}`.But while reading this `jsonobject` in **spring**  i am getting `?????`.The content type for this jsonobject while sending the request is `application/json;charset=utf-8`.I have added `produces="application/json;charset=utf-8"` to the rest controller even though it is not working.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "i am getting `?????`"? Is that in the debugger, in logs, in your web page output? You say you're "sending request" - to what? It's very unclear whether the problem is in receiving the text, parsing the text, sending output... please provide a lot more context.

Comment: while parsing the jsonobject which is in request means while i try get as jsonobject.getString("SUBJECT_AR") to some string it is printing "?????".

Comment: What do you mean by "it is printing"? In the debugger? In a page? Have you validated whether the request itself has been received correctly *before* being parsed as JSON? What's sending the request, and have you validated that it's *really* using UTF-8? There's still *so* much information missing here...

Comment: while sending request  my json is  {"SUBJECT_AR":"أهلا بك"} but when request comes to server i am getting json as {"SUBJECT_AR":"????"}

Comment: But you've skipped a number of places that things can go wrong: what do the bytes look like in the request? Are they being parsed correctly to a JSON string before that JSON is being parsed itself? And you *still* haven't explained how you're seeing those "?????". There's a lot more diagnostic work to do, and you need to put significantly more effort into explaining your context.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your `web.xml` (inside `web-app` tag) and retry:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you post your java method & `web.xml` ?